# How To trigger play button of flow player

Tags: php, jquery, flowplayer

I have integrated flowplayer in my website.

As a next step, I want to trigger its video play function, so that when a user plays a video, she/he will simply press a play button, that will call a function.

Can anybody please help me achiving that?

I am trying to do this:

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
$( ".fp-play" ).change(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
    });
</script>
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="artist_vidoe_player fl clear">
    <div class="flowplayer" data-swf="<?php echo WEB_URL; ?>assets/styles/frontend/js/flowplayer.swf" data-ratio="0.4167">
        <video>
            <source type="video/flv" src="<?php echo WEB_URL; ?>assets/styles/uploads/videos/<?php echo $rowvid->v_uploadname; ?>">
        </video>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left; margin-top:15px;">   
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <h1><?php echo $rowvid->v_filename; ?></h1>
        <p>258 Views</p>
        <p><img src="<?php echo WEB_URL; ?>assets/styles/frontend/images/stars_img.png" width="90" height="16" alt="" /></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above code dynamically generates my videos, but this is all not working for me anyway.

Comment: post your html content

Comment: We are not able to see any element with class name fp-play in html ?

Comment: it is created by plugin automatically..

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)** instead of `.change()` as well as using **[.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)** to trigger click event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $( ".fp-play" ).click(function() {
        alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
    }).trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Flowplayer features a javascript API and triggers the onStart event at the moment you start playing the video. You'll find more information here: http://flowplayer.org/documentation/events/clip.html